# Foundation for Email: CSS Classes not inlined

Tags: css, email, zurb-foundation, html-email, zurb-ink

I'm using Foundation for E-Mail to create templates. When I preview the templates by running `yarn start` everything works fine but when I `yarn build` the template my custom CSS classes will not be inlined.

For example

```html
<p class="pd-footer-contact">
   Lorem ipsum
</p>
```

will become

```html
<p class="pd-footer-contact" style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:10px;color:#4A4A4A;font-family:'Brandon Text',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;margin-bottom:10px;padding:0;text-align:left"><strong>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Although the inlined style is not the one from the CSS class. Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding how the inlining process works?

Comment: How do you currently import your custom styles? See https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/sass-guide.html and https://github.com/zurb/foundation-emails-template/tree/master/src/assets/scss

Comment: @DanielRuf I have put them in the `template/_template.scss` file

Comment: I can only guess without knowing the content of this file. I think it is generally better to open an issue at https://github.com/zurb/foundation-emails-template/issues as this is not a clear question and there are some information missing.

Comment: In general your styles should be applied, in addition to the default styles. Even as inlined styles.

Answer (score 0):

The styles you are seeing on the

tag are those assigned in the foundation.css file that is included on every email build.

Comment: There is no foundation.css file for Foundation Emails.

Comment: @Daniel the <installation_directory>/css/foundation.css file has the style values for the paragraph tag shown in the question.

Comment: This is about the SASS version of Foundation Emails, not the CSS version of Foundation Sites. These are two different frameworks.

Comment: https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/css-guide.html `css/foundation-emails.css`

Comment: @Daniel - I have and use the SASS version of Foundation Emails, it includes the foundation.css file, and when I code a paragraph tag in my index.html page it inserts the same styles as found in foundation.css with any overrides I have added either by class or in _settings.css. The original question asked where those styles were being generated for his paragraph without being coded by him, I believe that they are found in foundation.css. Foundation seems to generate a lot of inline defaults for every tag. If these defaults are not coming from foundation.css, where are they?

Comment: Yes the default styles are coming from the base styles. No, it is not about these. "my custom CSS classes will not be inlined"

Comment: OK, I thought the question was where those styles were coming from. When I use custom classes when building my email, I put them in src/assets/scss/app.scss and they are inlined by the build process.